# In ajax always error function is call. How to fix this problem?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

When i calling the ajax it goes to controller and after that in response it will executes error function.

ajax code :-

```
<script>
function showEmpDetails(empid)
{
    console.log(empid);
    $.ajax({
        url: "employeeInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: { empId: empid} ,
        success: function(data) { 

            console.log(data);
            $("#employeeDetails").html(data);
        },
          error: function () {
              alert("error");
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

The ajax control is going to the controller and it is also printing Hello.
Controller :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String empInfo(@RequestParam("empId") int employeeId, Model model) 
    {
        Employee findById = employeeMapper.findById(employeeId);
        model.addAttribute("employee", findById);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return "EMPINFO";
    }
```

Comment: If the `error` handler is being hit then the problem is with your server side logic. Check the request in dev tools to see what the exact response is. Hopefully it should give you an error to debug. One issue I can see is that you're sending `empId` yet the property is named `employeeId`

Comment: Also look at the arguments the `error` handler receives, as they have more information for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to set **dataType** to 'text' in your ajax call.

```js
<script>
    function showEmpDetails(empid) {
        console.log(empid);
        $.ajax({
            url: "employeeInfo",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { empId: empid },
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                $("#employeeDetails").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```